# Magento 1.9 Images not showing backend nor frontend

Tags: image, magento, magento-1.9

When i'm uploading pictures to my product in the product management, they do upload, but after that nothing happens. My final screen looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF9Ln.png

It should automatically show up at the top as i remember it. Before it worked just fine. If I look at my ftp client i do see the images showing up in the media/tmp/catalog/product/s/h folder (s/h for shirt). So that is my problem. They do not show up frontend nor backend, but they are on the server. I tried deleting .htacces file in media, server safe mode turned off, I believe I tried everything i could find on the internet.

I hope someone could help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked about read/write permissions of the directory? Also check the Magento and Apache logs.

Comment: yes i've checked those, they're 777. Where can i do that?

Comment: Magento logs are in /var/log/ for Apache depends what kind of developing environment are you using. I am using Vagrant and they are in /var/log/apache2/

Comment: Don't have a log directory in my var..

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/207975/

Comment: alright I did that, and tried it again but no log directory shows up.

Comment: Then there is no error in Magento logs, search for error in Apache logs.

Comment: I've got some files in there which I am not allowed to open, download or do anything with for some reason.